# Wpf binding is not working properly

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

My ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            // INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in ViewModelBase

            private String _propX;
            public String PropX
            {
                get { return _propX; }
                set
                {
                    if (_propX != value)
                    {
                        _propX = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => PropX);
                    }
                }
            }

            private String _propY;
            public String ServerIP
            {
                get { return _propY; }
                set
                {
                    if (_propY != value)
                    {
                        _propY = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ServerIP);
                    }
                }
            }

            public A()
            {
                this._propY = "000.000.000.000";
                this._propY = "000.000.000.000";
            }
        }

// EDIT
// This is the command that resets the properties
    private RelayCommand _resetFormCommand;
    public ICommand ResetConnectionFormCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resetFormCommand == null)
            {
                _resetFormCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ExecuteResetFormCommand(), param => this.CanExecuteResetFormCommand);
            }

            return _resetFormCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteResetFormCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this._propX) ||
                !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this._propY);
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteResetFormCommand()
    {
        this._propX = "";
        this._propY = "";
    }
```

My View xaml

```
<TextBox Name="propX" Text="{Binding PropX }" PreviewTextInput="textBox_PreviewTextInput" />
<TextBox Name="propY" Text="{Binding PropY }" PreviewTextInput="textBox_PreviewTextInput" />
<Border>
    <Button Content="Reset" Name="resetBtn" Command="{Binding ResetFormCommand}" />
</Border>
```

My View code behind

```
private MyViewModel vm;
public ConnectionUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new MyViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}

private void textBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateInput(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

The reset command resets the properties in my view model but the textboxes still contain their values, the binding is not working properly :(
Am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you please show the code of Action of your Reset Command?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the view model class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reset the properties, not the private members:

private void ExecuteResetFormCommand()
    {
        this.PropX = "";
        this.PropY = "";
    }

Comment: Works like a charm. Can you tell me please why this._propX does not work and this.PropX works well? Thank you

Comment: please notice that you raised PropertyChanged event in get accessor of the property

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged(() => PropX /*not _propX*/); I got it :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How are you resetting the values? You may be overriding the databinding when you reset the values. It would be helpful if you post the code that gets executed when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml-code you have to set the binding like:

```
<TextBox Name="propX" Text="{Binding PropX, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
```

Comment: User-editable properties such as TextBox.Text, ComboBox.Text, MenuItem.IsChecked, etc, have TwoWay as their default Mode value

Answer (score 0):

binding has to be two way in order for textbox to update itself from viewmodel

Comment: User-editable properties such as TextBox.Text, ComboBox.Text, MenuItem.IsChecked, etc, have TwoWay as their default Mode value

Comment: That's also what I thought, the reason why I didn't add the Mode attribute to the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code-behind, you have a property `ServerIP`, which I think you wanted to be named as `PropY`, since your `TextBox` binds to a `PropY` property.

```
<TextBox Name="propY" Text="{Binding PropY }" PreviewTextInput="textBox_PreviewTextInput" /
```

Also, you should be assigning the value to your *property* in your **ExecuteResetFormCommand** command, and not your *private member* since the *private member* does not trigger `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
private void ExecuteResetFormCommand()
{
    this.PropX = "";
    this.PropY = ""; // <-- Currently you have PropY declared as ServerIP
}
```

Comment: Forget the ServerIP, I work with it but I used propX and propY to simplify the question. I didn't know that a private member does not trigger INotifyPropertyChanged, I thought all members of my viewModel should trigger it since the viewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Nope, even if your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChange`, it has to be called for it to trigger an update. Which is why `RaisePropertyChanged(() => PropX);` is required, it triggers the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. Also, XAML can't read private variables.